# controlP5 number box variable printing

Tags: arduino, processing, control-p5

I am trying to print a variable in the number box using controlp5. The data is read from the serial port and stored in a variable. I want to print the value in the number box it is not working. when I print it in the console it shows the value, but not in the number box.

Here is my code:

```java
import controlP5.*;
import processing.serial.*;
ControlP5 cp5;
PFont font;
enter code here
void setup(){
size(300, 450); 
port = new Serial(this, "COM3", 19200);
cp5 = new ControlP5(this);
font = createFont("calibri light bold", 20);

cp5.addButton("increase").setPosition(100, 50)
.setSize(120, 70).setFont(font);

cp5.addButton("decrease").setPosition(100, 250)
.setSize(120, 70).setFont(font);

cp5.addNumberbox("temp").setPosition(100,160)
.setSize(120,70).setFont(font).setStringValue(val);

void draw(){
background(150, 0 , 150);`
 fill(0, 255, 0); 
textFont(font);
text("CONTROL", 80, 30);
if ( port.available() > 0) 
{ 
  val = port.readStringUntil('\n'); 
}
println(val); 


void increase(){


port.write('r');
}


void decrease(){
  port.write('b');
}
```

In this code, `val` is the variable and the data is read from the serial port and stored in `val` but `.setStringValue(val)` is not printing  the value of `val`. but if I print `val` in command console it shows the value of variable `val`.

Comment: Maybe print the value in the number box **after** you have read the value not before and only once?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to post valid code. This code will not compile as you're missing brackets, and we can't run it because it's not a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

I also recommend that you get into the habit of [debugging your code](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) to understand what's going on. Step through your code line-by-line to figure out when each line is happening.

Specifically, you're only setting the value here:

```
cp5.addNumberbox("temp").setPosition(100,160)
.setSize(120,70).setFont(font).setStringValue(val);
```

This line of code happens once at the beginning, when `val` is set to its default value. (Note that you don't even declare the variable in the code you've posted. **Please** post a MCVE.)

Later on in the code, you update the `val` variable:

```
if ( port.available() > 0) 
{ 
  val = port.readStringUntil('\n'); 
}
println(val);
```

But note that you are not updating the value that's displayed in your number box. **Updating the `val` variable does not automatically update places that have already used the variable.** You need to manually update the number box every time the value changes.

Answer (score 0):

**Use `.setValue()` rather than `.setStringValue()`.**

You will have to call `Integer.valueOf(val)` to cast it to a type the that your Numberbox will accept.

The resulting code may look like this:

```
if ( port.available() > 0) 
{ 
  val = port.readStringUntil('\n');
  cp5.get("temp").setValue(Integer.valueOf(val));
}
```

---

However, if you simply want to display the value, I'd recommend using *Processing's* `text()` or *CP5* `TextArea` or `Textlabel` since `Numberbox` is intended for use when you want to provide an easy way for the user to change / specify a value, rather than just display it. A Numberbox's value can be adjusted by scrolling the middle mouse button when the mouse is over the box.